# Retrofit query with multiple comma seperated values (Q=1,2,3,5,8)

Tags: android, retrofit

```
@GET("?bs")
Observable<Response> getSomething(@Query("type") String first, String second, String third)
```

I want the end result like this:

```
api.com/endpoint/type=first,second,third
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you use `Observable<Response> getSomething(@Query("type") String first)` and then call it as `getSomething("1,2,3,5,8")` ?

Comment: Good thought. I found though that you can pass in a String[]params too as a Query.

Comment: @Rosário Pereira Fernandes  I am using your solution, you wanna put it as an answer so I can mark it for cred? let me know

Comment: Just posted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single String parameter:

`Observable<Response> getSomething(@Query("type") String type)`

and then call it like this: `getSomething("1,2,3,5,8")` .

Comment: what if he wants to get these params dynamically.

Comment: Can always use the String's `split()` method. ;) @BishoyAbd

Comment: nice one, however, I would prefer to encapsulate this behavior as stated in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with an Idea

**create this class**

```
 public class QueryParameters {

    private List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();


    public QueryParameters(String... params) {
        this.params.addAll(Arrays.asList(params));
    }

    public void add(String param) {
        params.add(param);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int length = params.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i == length - 1)
                builder.append(params.get(i));
            else
                builder.append(params.get(i)).append(",");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

create an instance of `QueryParameter`, and add your parameters using the constructor or `add()` method then call `toString()` and pass the string to your `getSomething(@Query("commaSeparatedQuery")  String commaSeparatedQuery);`

Comment: I'm afraid your idea is not that good and unreasonably verbose for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin With Rxjava Sample

```
@GET("client/timeSlots")
fun getTimeSlot(
        @Query("size") size: Int = 14,
        @Query("page") page: Int = 1,
        @Query("cityId") cityId: Int,
        @Query("serviceIds",encoded = true) serviceIds: String?,
        ): Single<TimeSlotResponse>
```

Function to return a list of int in single String

```
    fun getServicesId(services: ArrayList<Int>): String? {
    var serviceName = ""
    services.forEach {
        serviceName += ",${it}"
    }
    serviceName = serviceName.removePrefix(",")
    return serviceName
}
```

The output will be like this

```
https://base_url/client/timeSlots?size=14&page=1&cityId=1&serviceIds=161,162,163,171
```